# WebStorm: can't catch <input/> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webstorm

I create a website with React.js with slider which use jQuery for autoscrolling. I have done it in the sandbox (Codepen.io), it works well. After I began to do it with "create-react-app" and WebStorm. What I have done:
In the command line I wrote:

```
"npm install create-react-app"
"npm install jquery"
"create-react-app my-app"
```

After that I have opened "my-app" with WebStorm 2018.2 (x86) and transferred into it all my code from the sandbox adding some "import" command. So the slider doesn't work now (it works like JavaScript code is absent). 
I deleted the extra code. That's what's left:
**JS code**

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery'

/*jshint esversion: 6 */
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div><div className = "slider"><input type = "radio" name = "slides" id = "slide1" /><input type = "radio" name = "slides" id = "slide2" /><input type = "radio" name = "slides" id = "slide3" /><input type = "radio" name = "slides" id = "slide4" /><input type = "radio" name = "slides" id = "slide5" />
            <input type = "radio" name = "slides" id = "slide6" /><div className = "captions"><div className = "c2" > Prediction 2 </div><div className = "c3"> Prediction 3 </div> <div className = "c4" > Prediction 4 </div> <div className = "c5" > Prediction 5 </div> 
            <div className = "c6" > Prediction 6 < /div></div></div> <div className = "controls" ><label htmlFor = "slide1" /><label htmlFor = "slide2" /><label htmlFor = "slide3" /><label htmlFor = "slide4" /><label htmlFor = "slide5" /><label htmlFor = "slide6" /></div></div>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));

//script for slider's autoscrolling

let inputs = $('input[type=radio]');
console.log(inputs);
let next;
let intervals = setInterval(() => {
    next = inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');
    if (!next.length) next = inputs.first();
    next.prop('checked', true);
}, 2000);

inputs.change(() => {
    clearInterval(intervals);
    intervals = setInterval(function() {
        next = inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');
        if (next.length) next.prop('checked', true);
        else inputs.first().prop('checked', true);
    }, 2000);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the console I see: `jQuery.fn.init(0)`. What I should do to catch inputs?

Comment: Use `document.ready(function(){...})`.

Comment: Great ! I added $(document).ready(()=>{  }) to my code and it works! Why does it need it? "$" is analog $(document).ready(()=>{  })

Comment: Before, you were trying to access the DOM before it was fully parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, @connexo, for the answer:

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
        let inputs = $('input[type=radio]');
        console.log(inputs);
        let next;
        let intervals = setInterval(() => {
            next = inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');
            if (!next.length) next = inputs.first();
            next.prop('checked', true);
        }, 2000);

        inputs.change(() => {
            clearInterval(intervals);
            intervals = setInterval(function() {
                next = inputs.filter(":checked").next('input');
                if (next.length) next.prop('checked', true);
                else inputs.first().prop('checked', true);
            }, 2000);
        });
    })
```

Now works! Become clear that without this statement i have tried to get access to input tags while them were not load.

Comment: Explain in your answer what went wrong and why that fixes the problem.